# Resize /var partition on a remote system (Linux Debian Lenny)

Tags: linux, debian, partition, remote

At a server that I only have access via ssh and vnc to (which means no booting from a "live" CD/DVD is possible), I would like to shrink the partition assigned to /var (in order to free some space for an additional partition). What would a good and safe way to do it?

Solution (based on David Spillet answer, provided that you have enough space on / to accommodate a copy of /var):

1. stop anything that is using /var where possible
2. remount /var readonly for good measure mount -f -oremount,ro /var (didn't seem to have any effect for me)
3. copy /var to / under a different name with mkdir /vartmp; cp -av /var/* /vartmp/
4. comment out the entry for /var in /etc/fstab
5. reboot
6. move things around with mv /var /varmount; mv /vartmp /var
7. reboot, partition
8. uncomment the entry for /var in /etc/fstap
9. reboot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have room on your root partition for the contents of /var you could:

1. stop anything that is using `/var` where possible
2. remount /var readonly for good measure `mount -f -oremount,ro /var`
3. copy `/var` to `/` under a different name with `mkdir /vartmp; cp -av /var/* /vartmp/`
4. move things around with `mv /var /varmount; mv /vartmp /var`
5. comment out the entry for `/var` in `/etc/fstab`
6. reboot

You should now have `/var` in place as-was on your root partition instead of its own. You can now resize the old partition as needed. Step 4 should let you rename the `/var` directory even though it is in use as a mount-point and otherwise busy (and proceses with open files there will track the change as the open files are not referred to by path+name, but instead by inode, once open).

If you don't have space on `/` but do on `/someotherfs` then you could try move it there with a symlink in `/` like so:

1. stop anything that is using `/var` where possible
2. remount /var readonly for good measure `mount -f -oremount,ro /var`
3. copy `/var` with `cp -av /var /someotherfs/var`
4. move things around with `mv /var /varmount; ln -s /someotherfs/var /var`
5. comment out the entry for `/var` in `/etc/fstab`
6. reboot

This is slightly more risky though as you need to be sure that `/someotherfs` gets mounted before `/var` when booting.

If you don't have room where you want to copy it to temporarily you might be able to reduce the size of `/var` by removing things like cached packages (`aptitude clean` on Debian style setups, there is no doubt an equivalent `yum` command), moving other stuff away (for instance, Debian keeps the default httpdocs in `/var/www` so if it is still there and you have lots of data in there, move it to another partition), and deleting files from `/var/log` that are not very recent (backing the up first, in case you do need to refer to them later).

As Zoredache says: what ever you do, make sure you are happy with your backup arrangement before proceeding.

Caveat: all the above is from memory, I've not tested it anywhere, follow at own risk!

Comment: Thanks for your effort explaining! Followed your first scenario with a little modification: couldn't rename /var to /varmount on step 4 ("device busy" - probably because /var is mounted straight to a partition), so first did 5), rebooted, and then "moved things around" (and rebooted again).

Comment: I was sure it would let you move it (I've deleted a whole directory structure while processes had files open within it before now) - you (re)learn something every day!

Comment: NB I don't believe these instructions will work on a modern version of Debian.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way is to [boot in single-user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub).  That way, `/var` won't even be mounted by default, so you can mess around with it all you like.

Comment: What would be the command to reboot in single-user mode?

Comment: I'd have to Google for the details, it's been a while.
It's not hard to find.

Comment: I've added a link.

Answer (score 0):

1. stop any services that may be using var (lsof | grep "/var")
2. umount /var
3. shrink /var
4. re-mount /var
5. restart the services you've stopped at 1.

Comment: Stuck at step 2.:
lsof | grep "/var" shows no services anymore (all killed), yet trying to unmount /var I get this: "umount: /var: device is busy"

Comment: You forgot step 0.  Make sure your backups are up-to-date and functional.

Comment: Try "umount -f" -- just make sure your current working directory isn't somewhere under /var or your shell will get killed (never hurts to have a backup login shell standing by, especially on remote machines).

Comment: @Geoff, here's what I get:
~ sudo umount -f /var                                                                                                                                                                 umount2: Device or resource busy
umount: /var: device is busy
umount2: Device or resource busy
umount: /var: device is busy

It didn't kick me out, but didn't do the unmount either. Earlier I tried "fuser -km /var" - that did kick me out (although I wasn't anywhere under /var), so, obviously, my ssh session depends on /var, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the console (e.g. keyboard-video-mouse via ethernet) then you can do:

1. `init 1` (and give root-password)
2. maybe a `systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd` is required only if you use it
3. `umount /var`
4. `e2fsck /dev/volume-where-var-is-in-your-system`
5. `resize2fs /dev/volume...` to whatever (in my case I wanted to shrink it so I used `-M`)
6. do more stuff (`lvresize` or whatever)

then reboot

Comment: This assumes LVM.

Answer (score 0):

Single user is the safest bet:

These instructions cover resizing the var LV/FS on a Red Hat 7.x system

Take inventory before going into single-user:

```
# df -h /var
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-var   13G  6.2G  5.9G  52% /var

# vgs
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg00         1   7   0 wz--n- <39.51g <2.63g

# lvs | grep var
  var      vg00       -wi-ao---- <12.86g
```

Boot into single user mode relevant to the platform you are using.

NOTE: The system will be accessible via /sysroot.

Activate vg00:

```
# lvm vgchange -ay vg00
```

Recreate LV device files:

```
# lvm vgmknodes -vv

# e2fsck -f /dev/vg00/var
```

To be safe, we’ll reduce the FS to 8GB and then the LV to 8.5GB (with a subsequent FS resize to fill it out):

```
# /sysroot/sbin/resize2fs -p /dev/vg00/var 8G
```

Some resize math:

```
VG PE size: PE Size 4.00 MiB

4M * 1024K = 4096K

8.5G * 1024K * 1024K = 8,912,896K

8,912,89 / 4096 = 2176 PEs
```

NOTE: I received the following error initially and had to manually override locking_type:
"Read-only set locking type. Write locks are prohibited."

```
# grep locking_type /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
locking_type = 4
```

Reduce LV:

```
# lvm lvreduce -l 2176 /dev/vg00/var --config 'global {locking_type=1}'
```

RE-execute resize to fill the LV container out to 8.5GB:

```
# /sysroot/sbin/resize2fs /dev/vg00/var
```

Confirm new size with:

# lvm lvs

```
# reboot
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this script before that

- Stop and Disable all applications and database services.
- before perfuming this script take a restart for the virtual machine.
  For a safety

after running this script you can start and enable the services back

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if script is being run as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root."
    exit 1
fi

# Display message about prerequisites
echo
echo "Before running this script, ensure the following:"
echo "- Stop all applications and database services."
echo "- Disable and restart the virtual machine."
echo

# Ask for confirmation to proceed or exit
read -p "Press Enter to continue or 'X' to exit: " confirm
if [ "$confirm" == "X" ] || [ "$confirm" == "x" ]; then
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit 0
fi

# Function to check if disk is part of a Volume Group
disk_in_vg() {
    pvs --noheadings -o pv_name,vg_name | grep -q "$1" && return 0 || return 1
}

# Function to check if logical volume exists
lv_exists() {
    lvdisplay "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 && return 0 || return 1
}

# Function to prompt user for action
prompt_action() {
    read -p "Do you want to replace existing 'var' with newly created logical volume? (yes/no/exit): " action
    case $action in
        [Yy][Ee][Ss])
            echo "Proceeding to replace 'lv_var' with newly created logical volume."
            ;;
        [Nn][Oo])
            echo "Exiting without replacing 'lv_var'."
            exit 0
            ;;
        [Ee][Xx][Ii][Tt])
            echo "Exiting."
            exit 0
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Invalid input. Please enter 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'."
            prompt_action
            ;;
    esac
}

# Step 1: List free disks with their names
echo "Available Free Disks:"
free_disks=$(lsblk -n -o NAME,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT | awk '$2=="disk" && $3=="" {print $1}')
echo "$free_disks"

# Prompt user to select a disk
read -p "Enter the name of the desired disk: " disk_name

# Validate if the disk exists
if [ ! -b "/dev/$disk_name" ]; then
    echo "Error: Disk '$disk_name' does not exist or is not a block device."
    exit 1
fi

# Check if the disk is part of a Volume Group
if disk_in_vg "/dev/$disk_name"; then
    echo "/dev/$disk_name is part of a Volume Group. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi

# Prompt user to provide Volume Group name
read -p "Enter the name for the Volume Group (Press Enter for default 'vg_var'): " vg_name
vg_name="${vg_name:-vg_var}"

# Step 2: Create Physical Volume
pvcreate "/dev/$disk_name"

# Step 3: Create Volume Group
vgcreate "$vg_name" "/dev/$disk_name"

# Step 4: Capture Free PE of Volume Group
free_pe=$(vgdisplay "$vg_name" | awk '/Free  PE \/ Size/ {print $5}')

# Step 5: Prompt user to input Logical Volume name
read -p "Enter the name for the Logical Volume (Press Enter for default 'lv_var'): " lv_name

# Set default logical volume name if not provided
lv_name="${lv_name:-lv_var}"

# Step 6: Create Logical Volume with Free PE Size
lvcreate -n "$lv_name" -l "+$free_pe" "$vg_name"

# Step 7: Prompt user for filesystem type (only ext4 or xfs)
while true; do
    read -p "Enter the filesystem type for the logical volume (only 'ext4' or 'xfs'): " filesystem_type
    case $filesystem_type in
        ext4|xfs)
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Invalid filesystem type. Please enter only 'ext4' or 'xfs'."
            ;;
    esac
done

# Step 8: Format newly created logical volume with chosen filesystem type
mkfs."$filesystem_type" "/dev/$vg_name/$lv_name"

# Step 9: Prompt user for action
prompt_action

# Step 10: Rsync data to new volume
rsync -aqxP /var/* "/mnt/$lv_name"

# Step 11: Unmount the old logical volume
umount "/dev/mapper/$vg_name-$lv_name" "/mnt/$lv_name"

# Step 12: Add entry to /etc/fstab with chosen filesystem type
echo "/dev/$vg_name/$lv_name /var $filesystem_type defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab

# Step 13: Display output of mount -a
echo "Mounting filesystems with the new configuration..."
mount -a

# Step 14: Prompt user for reboot confirmation
read -p "Do you want to reboot the server now? (yes/no): " reboot_choice
case $reboot_choice in
    [Yy][Ee][Ss])
        echo "Rebooting the server..."
        # Prompt for additional confirmation before rebooting
        read -p "Are you sure you want to reboot the server? (yes/no): " confirm_reboot
        case $confirm_reboot in
            [Yy][Ee][Ss])
                reboot
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Exiting without rebooting."
                exit 0
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
    [Nn][Oo])
        echo "Exiting without rebooting."
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid input. Exiting without rebooting."
        exit 0
        ;;
esac
```