# Is it possible to repartition a running Debian system without losing data

Tags: linux, debian, partition, hard-drive, parted

We need to resize the partition that is mounted to `/var` on a running machine. The only way to access it is via SSH, so live CD is not an option for us.

Can we repartition the file system without losing any data? (The system is freshly installed so there isn't any data yet.)

We tried `parted` but we got following warning:

> Error: File system was not cleanly unmounted!  You should run e2fsck. 
>   Modifying an unclean file system could cause severe corruption.

Comment: Here you go!
http://serverfault.com/questions/90270/resize-var-partition-on-a-remote-system-linux-debian-lenny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to stop all programs which use `/var`. You can find them with `fuser -m /var`.

Here you have to take care that you do not kill your SSH session. In order to keep SSH alive it might be necessary to temporarily reconfigure your SSH server to prevent any access to `/var`.

After that you can unmount your `/var` partition. And then you can use parted or any other partition tool, which also resizes the Ext2/3 filesystem.

It might be better to discuss this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/